What symmetry is this patterned octahedron?
This octahedron has a pattern made of three rotated half-hexagons.
I thought at first it had tetrahedral symmetry (due to the mirror), but maybe not.
So, to be very clear as to what the question is, what symmetry is this patterned octahedron?


I think it might be Pyritohedral symmetry, but I'm not entirely sure.

@Milten, It might be if it were drawn on a cube - but look at the vertices of a Pyritohedron - they have 3 edges, not 4.

It is pyritohedral. The numbers of vertices or edges don't matter. The symmetry group is generated by a 3-fold rotation and a reflection.

@Milten, and (mr__man) - I stand corrected (see below) it does belong to the pyritohedral symmetries but it is not a pyritohedron.

Consider a plane dividing the left and right halves of this picture, i.e., containing the viewpoint, the vertex nearest the eye, and the midpoint of the edge at the top rear. Reflection through that plane (i.e., swapping left and right in this photo) is a symmetry of the octahedron, but not of the patterned octahedron (because of the chirality of the pattern on the top face).
Similarly if you take a line from the upper right to the lower left vertex of the octahedron, spinning a quarter-turn about that line is a symmetry of the octahedron itself, but not of the patterned octahedron.
In short: definitely not the full symmetry group (as the first example shows), and not even the full orientation-preserving-symmetry group, as the second example shows.
I thought at first it had tetrahedral symmetry (due to the mirror), but maybe not?

In summary: "Not."
post-comment addition
In general, octahedral symmetry has a few generators: spin a quarter turn around an axis between two diametrically-opposed corners (call that $a$ for "axis"), reflect through a plane that contains a vertex and an edge of one face, and the origin (call that $r$), and spin one face so that its three vertices undergo a (1 2 3) permutation (call that $s$). Also (as OP points out), reflections through the three planes that contain four vertices are also symmetries, so let's pick one such plane (the one containing the top right, bottom left, and front vertex, say) and call reflection through that plane $q$.
With this pattern, $a$ is no longer a symmetry, but $a^2$ is. $r$ is no longer a symmetry at all, and being of order 2, we can just ignore it, I guess. And $s$ remains a symmetry. And so does $q$.
So I'd take some presentation of the group using $a, s, r, q$ and change it to one using $a^2, s$ and $q$, and see whether that covers everything. (In the original presentation, we have $a^4 = e$; in the revised presentation, we'd have $A^2 = e$, where $A$ is a name for $a^2$.)
I wish I had the time to say more here, but...

Great - so what symmetry is it? :-)

I have no idea -- I'm not great with finite groups, and have a deadline today anyhow.  Fortunately for me, that wasn't the question that was asked (at least not in the body of the question) :)

Fair enough. The question has been clarified.

Darn...and I thought I'd gotten the first complete answer. :)

Added a few notes.

This was the approach I would take as well - you can generate the full group of symmetries from just the two elements, and it's a subgroup of the octahedral symmetries. It's too long since I've classified finite groups but presumably @JohnHughes you are studying this at the moment and this is enough to identify it?

The three planes that contains four vertices have reflections.

Chris Lewis: Nope...I'm a computer scientist at this point, and last seriously looked at finite groups back in the 1980s when I taught a semester of Abstract Algebra.  Konchog: good point about those other reflections...I'll edit.

The answer is $\frac{2}m\bar3$ (Hermann–Mauguin notation) aka $T_h$ (Schoenflies notation); or written as (Coxeter notation):
$$\bullet\!\underset{4}{-}\!\circ\!-\!\circ$$
International Tables for Crystallography (2006). Vol. A" (PDF link via physics.ox.ac.uk (p.787) points out the Didodecahedron (also known as the diploid in crystallography - a rare crystal, but including pyrites, apparently, depicted on the left below) as an example of this symmetry.
Kudos to @John_hughes for helping me go the extra mile.


Is $\frac2m \bar3$ a typo or a notation I haven't seen before?

@TravisWillse Probably the latter. Don't worry, I haven't seen that sort of notation before either.

It looks like it's a notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann%E2%80%93Mauguin_notation#Point_groups

Exactly half of the $8$ symmetries of the (unpatterned) octahedron fixing a vertex preserve the pattern, so the symmetry group of the patterned octahedron is an index-$2$ subgroup of the full octahedral symmetry group, $O_h \cong S_4 \times C_2$. There are only $3$ such subgroups:

$O \cong S_4$, chiral octahedral symmetry,
$T_d \cong S_4$, full tetrahedral symmetry, and
$T_h \cong A_4 \times C_2$, pyritohedral symmetry .

Inversion through the center is a nontrivial central element of the symmetry group of the patterned octahedron, but $S_4$ has trivial center, so the only possibility is that the patterned octahedron has pyritohedral symmetry, $T_h$; it is denoted $[3^+, 4]$ in Coxeter notation and $m \bar3$ in Hermann–Mauguin notation.
This group has a unique order-$12$ subgroup, $T \cong A_4$ (oriented tetrahedral symmetry; $[3,3]^+$ in Coxeter, $23$ in H.–M.), which must thus be the chiral symmetry group of the patterned octahedron.

the reasoning is very nice- thanks!

Did you mean "this group has a unique order-2 subgroup"?

@return-true, I believe Travis meant order 12 and is talking about A4. Th is A4xZ2.

Right, I confused order with index.
